# What does the -exec option to 'find' do?

Tags: shell, unix, makefile

I am new to Makefile. I was going through an existing makefile and couldn't understand what it does. The line is as below.

```
find $(RELEASE_DIR) -depth -name  "*CVS" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

find command is used to find the strings. But I could not understand what this line exactly do. Please help to understand.

Comment: `man find` and `man rm`?

Comment: `man find` This removes all files named "*CVS" in the release directory of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The find command is there to search for files in a given directory.

```
find <directory> -option1 -option2
```

The option `-name "*CVS"` says that the command will search for files with CVS in the end of their name.

`-depth` means that the directories are traversed with the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search method.

`-exec rm -rf {} \;` tells find to execute the command `rm -rf` for every file that was found. `{}` is a placeholder for the currently found file and `\;` marks the end of the rm command.

Comment: {e,a} - Matches any one of a set of patterns separated by a comma. But here we are not giving any patterns . It has to find *CVS alone why do we need {} here.

Comment: {} is a place holder for the name of the file. If the {} would not be there, find would execute `rm -rf` instead of `rm -rf fooCVS`. I edited the answer for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This mean that it will scan the `$(RELEASE_DIR)` and for each file that have a name like *CVS we execute rm -rf, this mean delete it.

=> This command delete all files that contain `CVS` in the end of their name.